# Install drivers for Dell Inspiron 7420

Tags: installation, drivers, dell

I just installed ubuntu on my laptop Dell Inspiron 14R 7420.

How do I install the softwares which are required the shortcut functions, such as turning on light the keyboard <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>f6</kbd> or disable the mouse pad <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>f3</kbd>)?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to fix that, but you should look this (https://www.linuxwind.org/html/tag/dell-inspiron-7420), may be it can help you.

Comment: Isn,t it better if you can add some details about the solution. So reader can get a basic idea before visit the given URL.